Why it gives an error when I access the brawls stars api
when I access the api, it says
{"reason": "badRequest", "message": "Origin not allowed"}

here is my code:
import requests

api_key = "my-api"

headers = {
    'authority': 'api.brawlstars.com',
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'accept-language': 'ru,ru-RU;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'authorization': 'Bearer ' + api_key,
    'origin': 'https://developer.brawlstars.com',
    'referer': 'https://developer.brawlstars.com/',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
    'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

response = requests.get(f'https://api.brawlstars.com/v1/vouchers/dfe6be5d-b89d-451c-a898-44c4d3801658', headers=headers)
print(response.text)

There were many attempts to solve the error but nothing helped
